# Why cant I get forever to run on my Raspberry Pi 2 (node 0.10.2

Tags: raspbian, node.js, init.d

I've installed node 0.10.2 and forever on my raspberry pi. I had to update npm in order to install forever. I've created the following bash script to run my node app, but when I run it, it just prints the forever help without ever actually starting forever. Even when I simply try to execute just the one line

```
sudo /opt/node/bin/forever start -p /root/.forever --sourceDir=/home/pi/nodecode/server.js
```

it still does not seem to work. My only thoughts are that perhaps it's an incompatible version of forever

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/node/bin
export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/opt/node/lib/node_modules
export HOME=/root
USER=pi
OUT=/home/pi/nodejs.log

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "starting node"
    sudo -u $USER /opt/node/bin/forever start -p /root/.forever --sourceDir=/home/pi/nodecode/server.js 
    ;;
  stop)
    exec /opt/node/bin/forever stopall
    ;;
  *)

  echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/nodeup {start|stop}"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: have you tried node 5.6.0 or at least 4.2.1 LTS - much more up to date! look for the armv6 (pi1) or armv7 (pi2) install

Comment: hmmm, no I did not know that that there was an arm executable for 5.6.0, I'm actually trying to server angular.js and the version of angular im using requires 0.10.x

Comment: try `forever-service`. It's convenient, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the command was wrong

```
sudo -u $USER /opt/node/bin/forever start -p /root/.forever --sourceDir=/home/pi/nodecode/server.js 
should be

sudo -u $USER /opt/node/bin/forever start /home/pi/nodecode/server.js -p /root/.forever
```